# PHP/IIS6 outside firewall to connect to SQL Server inside firewall

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, iis-6, firewall

I have a simple order form written in PHP (running on Server A visible to the world) that our clients have access to that I want to have the data dump into our SQL Server 2005 (Server B) inside the firewall once they submit for processing.

I am not sure how what is the best way security-wise to set up a connection to our SQL server from outside the firewall and how to set it up: Trusted Connections, Kerberos: something else?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open a port in your firewall to allow connections from the webserver (server A) to your database server (server B). If server A is the only the machine that you ever want talking to server B from outside of the firewall, you should be able to configure a rule in your firewall that allows incoming traffic to the database server ONLY from server A (identified by IP address, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Opening the firewall and allowing either PHP to connect directly to your internal sql server is one way can be secured by only allowing ip locked/mac locked connections both via the sql server username and the firewall.

The other way would be an internal web service with authentication and have your external php post to the web service as well as opening a port and redirecting it for traffic (use a non-standard port external 88888 internal 80 for example) and also coupling it with ip/mac locked connections adds an extra level of security ontop of everything else also means you're not exposing your sql server externally only IIS (though its argueable which is more secure anyway :) )